Problem with bullmq and job's not starting possibly based on load?
I'm currently building an IMAP processor for iCloud mail because Apple's is so lame at processing rules. I'm only testing so there is not much load, but still I can repeatably start and stop the bull-board dashboard (all running locally on my beefy MacBook M3) and observe that some jobs will not start when bull-board is running. What is weird is I get no error I can find, just nothing in my log showing anything happened.
My code is very simple. It's just what I have. below.  What will happen is that in my new Worker(... code, I get the message about "about to process email", but then no log entry from inside await processEmail.  I'm setting the jobId with a guid so I know it's not rejected as a duplicate job, but still don't get how this can happen (again, only when bull-board is running).
Any thoughts on how I can better diagnose my issue?  Since the code in await processEmail is not getting called sometimes, I don't know where to start.
Thanks
const generalQueueName = "general-queue";
const generalQueue = new Queue(generalQueueName, {
  connection: {
    host: redisHost,
    port: redisPort,
  },
  prefix: process.env.REDIS_QUEUE_PREFIX ?? "email-queue-prefix-for-redis",
});

const generalWorker = new Worker(
  generalQueueName,
  async (job: Job) => {
    if (consoleLogging) {
      console.log("/src/app.ts: generalWorker: job.data.email: (about to call processEmail) ", job.data.email, " job.data: ", job.data);
    }
    await processEmail(job.data.email, job);
  },
  {
    concurrency: generalQueueConcurrency,
    connection: {
      host: redisHost,
      port: redisPort,
    },
    prefix: process.env.REDIS_QUEUE_PREFIX ?? "email-queue-prefix-for-redis",
  },
);

generalWorker.on("active", (job: Job) => {
  job?.log(`Job with id ${job.id} has started`);
});

generalWorker.on("completed", (job: Job) => {
  job?.log(`Job with id ${job.id} has been completed`);
});

generalWorker.on("error", (err) => {
  // log the error
  if (consoleLogging) {
    console.error("/src/app.ts: generalWorker: error: ", err);
  }
});

generalWorker.on("failed", (job?: Job) => {
  if (consoleLogging) {
    job?.log(`Job with id ${job?.id} has failed with ${job?.failedReason}`);
  }
});

